# How to retrieve the user’s phone number programmatically in iphone application?

Tags: iphone

As title how to?
I have tried the code from others sources:

```
id number = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@”SBFormattedPhoneNumber”];

NSLog(@”user phone number is %@”, number);
```

However it return NULL even thought I tested on device with firmware 2.2.1.
Any idea?

Comment: interesting read: http://www.kuberan.me/2011/03/your-mobile-numbers-are-being-stolen-by-websites/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible with the 2.2.1 SDK.

Wil Shipley worked very hard on this and talked about it at his presentation to a bay area cocoa heads group back in april.  Google wil shipley cocoa heads vimeo if you want to watch it.

I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by setting the number on the phone.  By default I do not think that the number is set on the iPhone but that can resolved by going into Settings->Phone->My Number.